# Declaration of widget class in ZK

Tags: zk

I am getting cls undefined in register() function.

```
var cls = zk.$import(clsnm);
cls.prototype.className = clsnm;
```

The documentation says

> Notice that the **class must be declared before calling this method.**
>   In other words, zk.$import(clsnm) must return the class of the
>   specified class name.

Where do I need to delcare class class name ?

Link of register function : [Link](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/6.5.1/jsdoc/zk/Widget.html#register%28_global_.String,%20boolean%29)

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Do you want to write your own `Widget`?

Comment: @Nabil A. yes and I have followed all the steps in tutorial.

Comment: Please post the .js for the class and the mold as well as your lang-addon.xml and zk.wpd